# ParentId field not available for SOQL queries for the Account object

Tags: apex, soql

We are currently using Financial Services Cloud. When we go to the Account objects through the UI, there is the field Parent Account with API name ParentId.

When I described the Account object through Workbench or look at the generate WSDL the ParentId doesn't exist for the Account object.

Basically, if we try

```
SELECT ParentId FROM Account
```

we get the error:

```
select parentid from account
       ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:8 No such column 'parentid' on entity 'Account'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

I tried the same query in a Dev org, and it worked just fine.

In the Setup -> Account settings, "Show View Hierarchy link on account pages" is enabled.

What am I missing? I believe this must be a very simple "thing" I'm forgetting here.

Googled a bunch and couldn't find anything :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost certainly need to fix your `Field Level Security`. Make sure your user has `Read` access.